# Using vb.net to copy data into different workbooks from excel

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel

I have this code where I want to put my data from excel into multiple arrays (via column data) so that each array is paste onto a new workbook. However, I have error  on this line :"  myValue.Add(WSheet.Cells(q, i).value)"

ListView1.Items.Add(myValue) is just for me to double check the values and it return correct values of those columns selected based on user input (textbox).

I hope someone can help me out here as I am beginner in vb.net

PS: I use arrays because I am dealing with large amount of data, but is not sure of how to proceed from there. I want to actually manipulate the arrays (using excel array formulas) before pasting into new workbook. Is it possible?

```
   'start process
    colNumO = TextBox1.Text
    colNum = TextBox1.Text + 3

    For i = 4 To colNum

        firstcell = WSheet.Cells(1, i)
        lastcell = firstcell.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
        lastrow = lastcell.Row
        entireColumn = WSheet.Range(firstcell, lastcell)


        columnArray = entireColumn.Value

        'put the entire column values into array
        Dim myArray As Object(,)  '<-- declared as 2D Array  
        myArray = ColumnArray   'store the content of each cell 

        For r As Integer = 1 To myArray.GetUpperBound(0)

            For c As Integer = 1 To myArray.GetUpperBound(1)
                myValue = myArray(r, c)

                ListView1.Items.Add(myValue)

                'put entire column value into one array(myValue)
                If lastrow >= 2 Then

                    For q = 2 To lastrow
                        myValue.Add(WSheet.Cells(q, i).value)

                        'store entire column values into one sheet
                        WBook2.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value = myValue
                    Next q

                End If

            Next c
        Next r

    Next I
```

Edited post:

```
    'start process
    colNumO = TextBox1.Text
    colNum = TextBox1.Text + 3

    For i = 4 To colNum

        lastrow = WSheet.Cells(WSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

        If LastRow >= 2 Then
            Dim ColValuesList As New List(Of String)
            For c = 1 To lastrow
                ColValuesList.Add(WSheet.Cells(c, i).value)
            Next c
            OverallValueList.Add(ColValuesList)
        End If
    Next i

    'copy column data into new worksheet
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 1
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    'Get the first worksheet in the book.
    Dim newworksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    With WBook2

        For j = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            newworksheet = WBook2.Worksheets(j)

            For Each columnValueList In OverallValueList
                For Each value In columnValueList

                    newworksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).value = value
                    rowIndex += 1

                Next value
                '    colIndex += 1

                j += 1


            Next columnValueList

        Next j


    End With
```

But the problem now is each list is pasted onto same worksheet of the workbook. What I want is different list into different workbooks. Is it possible?

Comment: What object type is `myValue`? And what is the Exception Message you are getting?

Comment: Hello, I have edited my code so now there is no problem. I have stated my problem under edited part.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Edited question, change the following code :

```
    For j = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        newworksheet = WBook2.Worksheets(j)

        For Each columnValueList In OverallValueList
            For Each value In columnValueList

                newworksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).value = value
                rowIndex += 1

            Next value
            '    colIndex += 1

            j += 1


        Next columnValueList

    Next j
```

To be :

```
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    For Each columnValueList In OverallValueList
        newworksheet = WBook2.Worksheets(j)            
        For Each value In columnValueList

            newworksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).value = value
            rowIndex += 1

        Next value
        'colIndex += 1

        j += 1
    Next columnValueList
```

This code will now iterate over each `list` and find the next `Worksheet` (if exists), it will then iterate over each `value` in the list and add it to the `Worksheet`